# Fast Way of Indexing Operator in Python (lambda i: l[i])

Tags: python, micro-optimization

Given an indexable data structure such as a list `l`, how can we get the fastest function that is equivalent to `lambda i: l[i]`? The problem of the lambda function is that it is Python and slows things down. There are some built-in operators in the `operator` module, but it appears that none of them can be used in this situation.

Comment: `l.__getitem__`?

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed to find a function faster than that. Technically you could do `l.__getitem__`, but I doubt that would be faster at all (certainly it would be close enough to be within the margin of error for any benchmarking you could do), and it's bad practice to call pseudo-private methods (the ones whose names start and end with two underscores) directly.

Comment: @mypetlion `l.__getitem__` is more than twice as fast in my testing, 7.5 seconds vs 16.3 seconds (for 1e8 calls).

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, repeated indexing of a list may be the wrong approach in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.__getitem__` is more than twice as fast, and since that's the object's own method, I doubt you can beat it.

```
>>> timeit('f(i)', 'l=[1,2,3]; i=1; f=lambda i:l[i]', number=10**8)
17.013631199999963
>>> timeit('f(i)', 'l=[1,2,3]; i=1; f=l.__getitem__', number=10**8)
7.722098399999936
```